# Как совместить click mouseover mouseout

Tags: jquery

Есть меню, в меню несколько пунктов, как сделать так чтобы при клике на какой-то из них, background менял цвет(допустим. серый), и оставался серым до тех пор, пока не нажали другой пункт меню. Но кроме этого нужен еще hover или mouseover/out (подскажите, что лучше). Так вот, чтобы при нажатом каком-то пункте mouseout не убирал цвет я использовал unbind. Дальше возникла проблема в том, что при нажатом пункте меню, при наведении на другие пункты меню они тоже закрашиваются, то цвет и вовсе убирается. Я в общем перепробовал тысячу раз и каждый раз какие-то косяки, запутался уже.. К тому же, хотел сделать так, чтобы при обновлении странички или переходе на какой то пункт меню он оставался подсвеченным, это я реализовал с помощью localStorage, вроде работает, но тоже не очень. Буду премного благодарен за любую помощь) Я нуб в js поэтому сильно не бейте

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("ul > li a").click(function ()
    {
        $("ul > li a").css({"background": "white"});
        $(this).css({"background": "#ccc"});
        $(this).unbind("mouseout");
    })
    .mouseover(function ()
    {
        $(this).css({"background": "#ccc"});
    })
    .mouseout(function ()
    {
        $(this).css({"background": "white"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подстветки активного (нажатого) пункта меню намного проще использовать дополнительный класс, например, `.active`, и описывать стили для него непосредственно в css. С ховером тоже самое - пишите все стили в css, тогда не придется вешать лишние обработчики в js.

```js
$('ul li a').on('click', function() {
  var list = $(this).closest('ul');
  list.find('li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul li a.active,
ul li a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a>Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li><a>Пункт 4</a></li>
  <li><a>Пункт 5</a></li>
</ul>
```